# How do I resolve the dns issues I'm having with my docker containers?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, knex.js

I am working on a Node app with a Postgres database and React frontend. I've created a docker-compose file to spin up 3 containers inside of a custom named network. When I initially made my database connection using pg it worked fine as I was able to perform queries against the database and see them in postman and on the localhost for the server. I have now added knex to the setup to make things a bit easier and seem to be having some issues. I have the following in my knexfile.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
    development: {
        client: "postgresql",
        connection: process.env.DB_URL,
        migrations: {
            directory: "migrations",
            tableName: "migrations",
        },
    },
};
```

and here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  frontend:
    build: client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - quality-review
    container_name: frontend-docker
    restart: always
    links:
      - backend

  backend:
    build: server
    env_file:
      - ./server/.env
    ports:
      - "3500:3500"
    networks:
      - quality-review
    container_name: backend-docker
    restart: always
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13.2
    ports:
      - "6000:5432"
    networks:
      - quality-review
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: took my password out :)
    volumes:
      - ./postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    container_name: database_docker
    restart: always

networks:
  quality-review:
    external: true
    name: quality-review
```

I was able to use knex migrate:make to create a new migration file. Now I'm trying to use knex migrate:latest but am getting the following error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
```

From all the research I've been doing this seems to be an issue with resolving the DNS name. I thought by using these inside a custom docker network they'd all be able to talk with each other properly but that does not seem to be the case. I'm kind of lost as to where to head from here as I've spent the last 4 hours or so digging through all I can find on this issue. If anyone has any thoughts I'm open to help. TIA!

Comment: Knex is running on local machine or inside docker? Also I don't see anywhere you passing `DB_URL` in your compose config?

Comment: I've got process.env.DB_URL in the knexfile.js. Knex should be installing as I run docker-compose up since it is part of the package.json and dependencies are being installed by my RUN commands in my Dockerfiles.

Comment: I meant where is the value being set for `DB_URL` and what is that value? Where are you running these knex commands? inside the backend or the frontend service?

Comment: ah I understand. The DB_URL is in my .env file and is set as postgresql://postgres:*******@db:5432/quality_strategies (******* is my password). The connection was working fine before I added knex, even within the docker set up. I changed to db instead of localhost as that was not working properly. db is the name of the service in my compose file

Comment: Try with `database_docker` instead of `db`

Comment: Good thought and thank you! - tried that in the DB_URL but now the error just says Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND database_docker
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
instead...

Comment: Can you disable the external network you are using and see if that mat be creating the problem?

Comment: I added the external network because I had read that on the default bridge network containers sometimes don't talk to each other. This did not work either.

Comment: Take down the whole compose `docker-compose down -v` and recreate it, I don't see any issues as such might be a temporary glitch, also restart docker service once

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look through the code. Unfortunately this did not work. Still getting the same error.